# What is the time limit to undo upvotes/downvotes on posts?

Tags: support, voting, undo

If I want to undo my votes on any question or answer, within how much time can I undo, from the time I voted?

Is there any specific time span within which I have to do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After you vote, your vote is locked in [5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/168333).

After those 5 minutes, you cannot undo or change your vote until a post is edited.

The purpose of vote lock-in is to prevent tactical downvoting. "Tactical downvoting" is when a user downvotes competing answers to make their own answer look better. It makes other answers look less good, and makes that user's own answer look a bit better compared to the others. This also causes the user's own answer to be higher in the list, which makes it more visible and increases its change of getting more votes.

Obviously this is not desirable; votes should be based on the value of an answer. Votes should not be cast to "win" a competition.

We have a -1 penalty for downvoting competing answers; but if you revert your vote, you get that 1 point back. By locking votes, the "tactical downvoter" has to do more work to get their reputation points back.

Comment: What is "tactical downvoting"?

Comment: @NovaLogic "Tactical downvoting" is downvoting competing answers, with the intention of giving them a lower ranking compared to one's own answer. It makes one's own answer look better in comparison, and gets one's own answer ranked higher - thus more likely to attract more votes. We strongly discourage this practice, or course.

Comment: The real strategy against tactical down voting would be to prevent the answering person from down voting any other answers, if he had caste his vote before answering, the action of answering automatically remove the votes on other answers. Vote lock is only to prevent people from abusing vote reversal and driving some user crazy.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Suppose you encountered a question that had genuinely bad answers. And you know a much better answer. Now you'd have to choose between (a) downvoting the bad answers, or (b) providing a good one.

Comment: But the restriction is meaningless, because you can edit the question or answer yourself and then change your vote. And besides, changing your mind is GOOD. It should not be discouraged. This entire rule is just silly and should be abolished. It serves no purpose.

Comment: @matt If you are above 2000 points you can. I recall one case of a user who accidentally downvoted and made a trivial edit to correct it. But I'm not aware of large-scale abuse. If _all_ answers on a post have trivial edits followed by vote reversals, that would be suspicious. ... I wouldn't be surprised if there was a script to detect that pattern.

Comment: It’s not abuse. I rethink my vote a LOT. I use the minimal edit and change vote technique a LOT. I have to, because the time limit is stupid.

Comment: And I don’t believe the rule has anything to do with tactical down voting.

Comment: If you rethink your votes a lot then perhaps you aren't voting for the right reasons. Sure sometimes you start to answer, do some research and realise the other persons answer was not as bad as it seemed. But this should be rare (and you should encourage that other user to add the reasoning - that you presumably both discovered - to their question) - I promise nothing here is meant condescendingly (I can't figure out how better to reword that first sentence)

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That would be a terrible method; it fails to address the real problem and shoves a certain behavior down users' throats. At SO we place a lot of value on user agency.

Comment: @matt The rule _is_ there because of tactical downvoting; Jeff Atwood himself [pointed this out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/168333). Whether or not it's working as intended... that's open for debate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the correlation you're drawing between tactical downvoting and vote locking. Could you edit some of the clarifications you answered as comments into your answer to make this clearer?

Comment: @MMAdams the idea with tactical downvoting is that after your answer pulls ahead you could undownvote the other answers and get your rep back but your answer will still be perceived as best. If it's locked, you can't

Comment: Ok, well, the far fetched behavior suggested in your revised answer would never have occurred to me in a million years. So the rule seems even more pointless.

Comment: And your explanation doesn’t explain why it’s so inconvenient to change my vote on a QUESTION.

Comment: @matt Good point. My best guess is that tactical downvoting of questions was something Jeff and Joel worried about when they created the site. IIRC downvoting questions once cost a point of rep too, many years ago. Nowadays there's hardly a point in tactically downvoting questions; new questions get pushed off the front page in just a few minutes anyway.

Comment: It does not make sens, look if i really want my answer to look better, then i would simply downvote other's answer, without reversal. And -2 for each answer downvoted would not hold me form doing it. The fact that you can actually vote in any way on competing answer IS the problem. It's like running for being president, but you are allowed to downvote one time on all your competitor. And as there is often not much votes... one vote is actually a lot.

Comment: I don't mean that it is supposed to be a competition, but i saw it once : three good answers on a question, and each answer had -2 count. Why ? all answerers though it was a competition, so they cast hate downvotes. -2 everywhere.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I believe that's why downvoting answers has a trivial -1 rep penalty: to discourage just leaving a downvote anyway.

Comment: @Justin Ha !  -1 is not THAT discouraging. If I was a rep farmer, I could not care less about -1 vs. my answer on top. I love SO a lot, but I can't stop thinking the vote system is flawed. Argue with me as much as you want, the only acceptable arguments are that it's going to be too tough to rethink it better... which is also NOT true