# Why can't I undo my upvote casted long time back?

Tags: discussion, voting, undo

I returned to a question asked after a few months and realized that the answer I upvoted is actually not correct. My skills in that particular area have improved and I don't agree with the answer anymore and would like to not support it by my upvote.

A similar scenario is discussed here - [What is the time limit to undo upvotes/downvotes on posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365805/what-is-the-time-limit-to-undo-upvotes-downvotes-on-posts)

But I believe what I am asking has nothing to do with the "tactical downvoting" as it is not about doing/undoing a downvote. Secondly, I don't have any answer there (yet).

Comment: Is there anything in the answer you could edit to fix without going against the thrust of the author's argument? If so, you can edit it to unlock the votes. But, please, don't make trivial edits to do so.

Comment: No, the answer is just wrong. It can not be fixed and yes, I am against to trivially edit the answer just to undo upvote.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, there's no way to retract your vote. It's inconvenient, but that's the way the site is designed, for now.

Comment: Ok in that case, I will drop a comment in the question.

Comment: If you can fix grammar or spelling or punctuation that's not trivial and allows you to retract your upvote.

Comment: Commenting seems like the best course of action here. The OP may never reply, but at least others *may* read your points. Votes are always based on your opinion of the post at the time; and opinions and technology can and does change. There's nothing wrong with the vote being there, if you felt it was right at the time, as you agreed with its answer and so the vote served its purpose. The same is true for downvotes (though hopefully people will edit their answer to address any constructive comments, if someone leaves them, and not play the childish revenge vote game...)

Comment: in such a case, I _do_ trivially edit the answer and leave both an edit comment and a plain comment explaining why .. an incorrectly voted post is not just _inconvenient_, IMO.

Comment: @kleopatra Problem is, if *everyone* did that, we'd have a bunch of old posts bumped to the homepage. Sure, one person doing it isn't going to have an impact. But if *everyone* did it? That's another story. I agree, saying it's inconvenient is a bit of an understatement, but... that's just how things are, for now.

Comment: If your knowledge has now advanced to the point where you could post a *better* answer (that's not already written), write a better answer. Then comment (as others have suggested) and point to your answer, explaining why it's more correct. Your writing an answer will "bump" the question to the home page so that others see it and, perhaps, vote it up (thus reducing the "value" of the answer you believe is incorrect). You don't say, but if this is your own question you can mark your contribution as the answer, after a couple of days.

Comment: Funny how almost identical https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392931/no-time-shown-until-i-can-undo-my-vote-for-an-answer get's -1 votes and this on +7 on the same week...

Comment: @Rob please sync up with Cody on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392931/no-time-shown-until-i-can-undo-my-vote-for-an-answer#comment749305_392931 (about whether it is ok to make trivial edit in such case).